On proving that an Artin L-function is cusp form
I am reading the article by JEAN-PIERRE SERRE, On a Theorem of Jordan, BULLETIN  OF THE AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY, 2003. I have problem in the following part:

Since $S_{3}$ is a dihedral group, Hecke’s theory applies and shows that the power series $ F = \sum_{m=1}^{∞} a_{m}q^{m} $with the same coefficients as $L(ρ,s)$ is a cusp form of weight 1
and level 23, with respect to the character ($\frac{p}{23} $). The explicit expressions of F given in the text can be checked by standard modular methods.

Here  $F=\eta(\tau)\eta(23\tau)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-q^k)(1-q^{23k}) $ and $L(ρ,s)$ is the Artin L-function associated to a  representation $ρ :S_{3}→\text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{C}) $.
My question - what does mean that "Since $S_{3}$ is a dihedral group, Hecke’s theory shows that F is cusp form of weight 1 and level 23, with respect to the character $(\frac{p}{23} )$ "? Is there a reference or a theorem which implies this ?
And also, what does he means by the modular method ?
